# Apache MyFaces Trinidad: <tr:column/> generate html

Tags: java, html, jsf-1.2, trinidad

The html that generate from tr:table contains th for the header and td for the row data
which is good.

my problem is that i want to style to the 'th' element

When I added style to tr:outputText this does not effect.

The style that I trying to add is - text-align:right

how can i do this how can I control the html that being generated from jsf (Trinidad is this case)

my code

```
 <tr:table value="#{myManagedBean.allEmployees}"
      bandingInterval="2" banding="row" var="emp">
  <tr:column>
      <f:facet name="header">
      <tr:outputText value="Name"/>
     </f:facet>
     <tr:outputText value="#{emp.ename}"/>
  </tr:column>
  <tr:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
     <tr:outputText value="Department Number"/>
    </f:facet>
    <tr:outputText value="#{emp.deptno}"/>
  </tr:column>
</tr:table>
```

Any one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can fiddle around with the trinidad skin selectors. So put this inside your trinidad-skin.css:

```
af|column::sortable-header-text
{
    text-align: right;
}
```

Further Information for trinidad-skinning:
http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/skin-selectors.html